# Discord and TeamSpeak 3 clients randomly closing

Tags: release-hera, games

I have a problem with Discord and TeamSpeak 3 clients on elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera. After a few hours of using either, the client just closes, no error message, nothing. On TS3 when I connect back to the server, my previous connection is still visible, but it times out after a minute. At first I thought that Linux port of Discord just does that, because it is pretty buggy and freezes a lot, but I was surprised to see that TS3 does the same, despite being the "stable and reliable one". So maybe elementary OS has a problem with voice chat apps? Has anyone else experienced the same issue? Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Edit: Today TeamSpeak3 just froze and I had to kill it.My friends, who are all on Windows, had 0 issues with TS3 so I guess the problem is with elementary...

Answer (score 0):

Did you get them from flatpak? I've experienced problems with Discord when getting it from flatpak before. I usually just get the .deb file from Discord site. I've yet to had a problem doing it like that. Not sure about teamspeak though, sorry.

Comment: No, I got the .deb file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen with Discord a few times, using 5.1.2. I haven't found a solution, but wanted to chime in to say you're not alone.